# MySQL error 1064 al EJECUTAR un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql

Estoy teniendo un error que me está volviendo loco al crear un procedimiento almacenado, SQL dinámico. Y no lo puedo encontrar. No solo no veo (quizás estoy demasiado ciego ya) el error sino que además tengo procedimientos almacenados similares que se ejecutan sin problemas. Aquí el código:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_sue_conceptos_afip_iu`(in iID int,
in cDescripcion varchar(200),
in cCodigo_AFIP varchar(6),
in bSistema bit,
in cOperador varchar(20))
BEGIN
    set @cInstruccion = "";
    set @cWhere       = " where";
    
    if iID = 0 then
        set @cInstruccion = "insert into" ;
    else
        set @cInstruccion = "update" ;
    end if;

    set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion," sue_conceptos_afip set");
    set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion," desripcion = cDescripcion,");
    set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion," codigo_afip = cCodigo_AFIP,");
    set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion," sistema = bSistema,");

    if iID = 0 then
        set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion," baja = false,");
        set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion," operador = cOperador,");
        set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion," fecha_creacion = now(),");
    end if;

    set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion," operador_modif = cOperador,");
    set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion," fecha_modif = now()");

    if iID <> 0 then
        set @cWhere       = concat(@cWhere,"id = iID");
        set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion,@cWhere);
    end if;

    set @cInstruccion = concat(@cInstruccion,";");

    prepare proceso from @cInstrucccion;
    execute proceso;
    deallocate prepare proceso;

    if iID <> 0 then
        set iID = last_insert_id();
    end if;
END
```

Puesto que el error me surgió utilizando MySQL desde Visual FoxPro 9.0, lo testeo de la siguiente manera, en una pestaña de query:

```
call sp_sue_conceptos_afip_iu(0,"Prueba","100000",false,"MartinLezama");
```

El error que me brinda MySQL es:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

Ahora bien, por lo que estoy interpretando, si bien me dejó guardar el procedimiento almacenado cuando lo redacté, en la ejecución encuentra algo que no le gusta directamente al inicio. Ya me estoy volviendo loco, chequeo y rechequeo y veo que está todo bien. *O ya no veo una vaca arriba de un burro o hay algo que se me está escapando.*

Envío cinco parámetros. En sucesión, un entero, dos de texto, un booleano y otro varchar, la cantidad de parámetros que paso al ejecutar está bien, su valor está bien, lo testeo desde Visual FoxPro y da error, lo testeo en el Workbench de MySQL y da error y ya no sé por dónde más buscar. Encima es algo que ya me está poniendo nervioso, puesto que tengo muchísima experiencia de programación en Visual FoxPro (alrededor de 30 años)... pero nada en MySQL jaja, *y me pasa lo que a cualquier señor cascarrabias de mediana edad cuando tiene que aprender algo nuevo a los taitantos.*

Comment: ¿Typo en _desripcion_? Además: ¿te fijaste qué contiene `@cInstruccion` cuando lo ejecutás?

Comment: Fijate que lo primero que hago es setear cInstrucción = "" y cWhere, así que ambas arrancan seteadas como texto. ¿Puede estar ahí la falla? ¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de setear una cadena vacía en MySQL? Porque me canta línea 1, así que la falla muy probablemente sea ese set. Aunque como ya dije, tengo varios procedimientos almacenados similares en donde lo primero que hago es setear en blanco las variables que voy a utilizar para concatenar, y andan.

Comment: La lógica del procedimiento sería: si viene con el ID en 0 es un insert. Si ID trae un valor distinto de 0 sería un update. Y que dinámicamente construya la instrucción para tener insert y update dentro del mismo procedimiento.

Comment: ¿Y el `VALUES` del `INSERT INTO`? ¿Y el `SET` del `UPDATE`?

Comment: prepare proceso from `cInstrucccion` tiene 3 C, sólo son 2 según el nombre de la variable

Comment: @javdromero graciasssss! ES ESO. Evidentemente a las 5 de la mañana ya no veía una vaca arriba de un burro!

Comment: @padaleiana el SET estaba acá:

    set cInstruccion = concat(cInstruccion," sue_conceptos_afip set");

(le quité las arrobas al tipearlo acá para que no lo interpretase como una cita). El INSERT... SET no lleva la instrucción VALUES, justamente utilizo INSERT... SET para poder construir el comando de la misma manera para un INSERT que para un UPDATE.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por el tiempo!!!

Comment: Tenés razón, hacés uso de una sintaxis que no suele ser tan utilizada. De todos modos, te recomiendo que intentes ver qué contiene `@cInstruccion` antes de ejecutar `prepare proceso from @cInstrucccion;`, para ver si se te escapó alguna coma, espacio, etc.

Comment: Como dijo @javdromero, estaba ahí. Había puesto instruCCCion y era instruCCion. Yo lo buscaba arriba porque me decía NULL en la línea 1, pero claro, al ser dinámico, la línea 1 para MySQL era cuando trataba de preparar la sentencia y se encontraba con una C de más en cInstruccion.

Comment: @padaleiana tal y cual, no es tan utilizada pero la utilidad es que si tengo que hacer el INSERT tradicional, la gramática es absolutamente distinta, ya que tengo que poner primero todos los campos y después todos los values. El INSERT...SET (que no recuerdo que estuviese de entrada en SQL) apunta justamente a eso, a que si construís SQL dinámico, puedas construir tu INSERT o tu UPDATE del mismo modo. Es muy útil para cuando querés hacer cosas como las que hice en ese procedimiento.

Comment: Resumen: Era un typo por una letra. Fin.

Comment: @javdromero sí sí, era eso, muchísimas gracias, ya no sabía dónde buscar.